# What to do when briefcases in the bag run out?

Tags: black-friday

Near the end of the game, when a price adjustment occurs 9 or 10 briefcases can be puled from the bag, but only 5 will be replaced.

I played recently where the bag ran out of cases except for these 5 that got added. In this situation, everybody knows exactly what will come out and the game loses the randomness which the stock market is meant to have.

Is there any rule for what to do in this situation, should a stalemate be declared, or is this normal and acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

The rules say that if there aren't enough briefcases in the bag, you just take all remaining briefcases from the bag. So you're right that this could be a problem, but at least Friedemann Friese seems to think it's acceptable.

This situation never happened in any of my games, so maybe it's a rare exceptional case.